# Couchbase client throws TimeoutException after adding a node in couchbase cluster

Tags: java, scala, couchbase

```
couchbase-server-community         4.0.0-4051-1
"com.couchbase.client" % "java-client" % "2.1.6",
```

We have a Couchbase cluster of 19 nodes and around 150 client boxes connect to this cluster. We added one more node today and we started to get the following exception from some of the client boxes. The exception goes away once the client boxes are restarted, but ideally this should not happen. I am not able to find if there is a bug in the above mentioned client version, which might cause this. Anyone has any idea/suggestion regarding this?

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.counter(CouchbaseBucket.java:656) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.counter(CouchbaseBucket.java:641) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

Comment: Is this during a rebalance? If you're operating near capacity, add a node, and rebalance, there's a good chance you'll get timeouts.

Comment: @Hod Yes, our nodes were near capacity, however we saw Timeout after rebalance as well.